# Bleeding bubbles through stain

Tags: finishing, wood, staining

Okay I saw another question about bleeding through paint but this is stain so it may have a different solution.

I sanded, used prestain conditioner, and minwax stain on a desk I’m attempting to restore. I noticed after coming down hours after the stain set that there were sticky bubbles of stain that popped up (after I wiped excess off).

Thinking I just didn’t wipe enough off, I sanded it back down to Redo the stain, bit after sanding it back down, grabbing a coffee, and getting ready to recoat it, I see the wood is just bleeding. See the photo below

[image]

What can I do before applying my preconditioner and stain to stop the wood from bleeding?

Comment: Rewind a bit, you say you're restoring the table so what kind of condition was it in before you started? The surface currently doesn't look great so I'm guessing it was in pretty rough shape beforehand so contamination of the wood is a possibility. P.S. wood looks like oak, so "conditioner" was not needed and actually detrimental to the process since it blocks stain entry and will greatly limit how dark the wood can go.